# How to use socket.io properly with express app

Tags: node.js, rest, express, socket.io

I wonder how do I use socket.io properly with my express app.

I have a REST API written in express/node.js and I want to use socket.io to add real-time feature for my app. Consider that I want to do something I can do just by sending a request to my REST API. What should I do with socket.io? Should I send request to the REST API and send socket.io client the result of the process or handle the whole process within socket.io emitter and then send the result to socket.io client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not that clear but from what I'm getting from it, is that you want to know what you would use it for that you cant already do with your current API?

The short answer is, well nothing really.. Websockets are just the natural progression of API's and the need for a more 'real-time' interface between systems.

Old methods (and still used and relevant for the right use case) is long polling where you keep checking back to the server for updated items and if so grab them.. This works but it can be expensive in terms of establishing a connection, performing a lookup, then closing a connection.

websockets keep that connection open, allowing both the client and server to communicate real time. So for example, lets say you make an update to your backend data and want users to get that update, using long polling you would rely on each client to ping back to the server, check if there is an update and if so grab it. This can cause lags between updates, some users have updated data while other do not etc.

Now, take the same scenario with websockets, you make an update to the backend data, hit submit, this then emits to your socket server. Socket server takes the call, performs the task ( grabs updated data ) and emits it to the users, each connected user instantly gets that update.

Socket servers are typically used for things like real time chats or polling where packets are smaller but they are also used for web games etc. Depending on the size of your payloads will determine how best to send data back and forth because the larger the payload the more resources / bandwidth it will take on the socket server so its something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your time on answering. This is really explaining. I understand the real use cases of socket.io.